# strings comparison in PHP

Tags: php, string

I feel like the biggest fool on the planet earth.  But I am looping through a text file and attempting to compare each line and find the line breaks... You know... "\n".  But I can't seem to compare the strings!!!!
Here is what I am doing.

```
    $filename = 'StatesCities.txt';
$file = file($filename);
$matchedLines = array();

foreach($file as $line) {     
    $matchesLines[] = $line;
    if(strcmp($line, "La Mesa") == 0)
    {
        echo("Yeah");
    }
    echo($line);
    echo("<br />");
}
```

Comment: trim the line: trim($line) first.

Comment: $matchesLines[] = $line;->What do you want to do with this line?

Comment: That line is for functionality that I plan to add later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to remove the line breaks? If that's the case then you can explode them.

```
$file = file_get_contents( $file_path );
$page = explode( "\n", $file );
//Now they're gone

foreach( $page as $line )
{
  if( strpos( $line, 'searchfor' ) !== false )
  {
     //do this
  }
}
```

The strpos is how I usually search in a string, just make sure to use !== which checks for false not false or 0. If the string your looking for has a strpos of 0 ( first character ) it would return a false positive if you don't check for the type with !==. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your question says you're looking for "\n" but your code is looking for "La Mesa".  Perhaps you wanted to say

```
 if (strpos($line, "\n"))
```

?

Comment: That was just a test value to see if I could actually compare the strings.  Which I can't

Comment: You have to be careful with strpos if the string you are searching for starts at the first character this function will read if(0) which will yield the wrong result. If you use this function make sure to add the !== operator. if( strpos( $line, "\n" ) !== false ).

Answer (score 0):

The `file()` function will maintain newline characters (`\n`) in the array that it creates by default.  See [here](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) for more info; in particular, the `flags` section.  To fix your problem...

Instead of this:

```
$file = file($filename);
```

Use this:

```
$file = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```